# How do I verify emails on a contact form?

Tags: 8, emails

I want to implement a functionality where anonymous users can contact node authors. I have created a contact form with email field for each node. I would like to send an email verification link to the email address for email ownership confirmation. The form submit should be complete only when that happens.

What would be the best approach to handle this? There is a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_field_verification) in drupal 7 which could work but I didn't come across anything for D8. Will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What do you mean with verify. If it looks like a real email. If it is connected to a real mail server. Or that it actually works.

Comment: The person submitting the form should have access to the email. I want to send a link to the email address for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

As LvB points out in its comment, you cannot really check email on-the-fly.

I think you should store the submission as moderated, send a confirmation email to the frontend user, and only follow-up the submission to the author when the user clicks the confirmation the email.

You'll get the same result which is only send confirmed contacts to author, like a to two-step confirmation. You could have a webform handler to manage the submission status. Check https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook to start seeing what a webform handler could do.

There is a module under development to do so https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_double_opt_in but hey, it's still beta.

Comment: You can not check email at all. The protocols involved do not allow a check like that. All you can try (as suggested) is do a double take. But whether you are allowed to do so is another matter (it could be considered spam by local law). Safest bet is to  either require an account or to to not validate it at all. (Possibly with a block list). And remember, do not make the cure worse that the disease. A mail validation could do that (quite a few sales people found that out)

Comment: Just trying to answer the question, without questionning the reason why. Anyway, I think the best way is your suggestion to make people having an account. This is proper and straightforward and you just may propose it as an answer.

Comment: This method would work. It's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

For validating an email just use client side validation in that case. [mdn form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)
This will use the browsers checks for valid email and not send the form to you unless it’s valid.

For verifying an email I would say use Drupal accounts (that already has a superior methode for email verification.)

Btw. you can not check if email is valid at all.
The protocols involved do not allow a check like that.
What you can do is try and send a message and hope it arrives at the other end.
This would be a (as suggested) double take. But whether you are allowed to do so is another matter (it could be considered spam by local law). Safest bet is to either require an account or to to not validate it at all. (Possibly with a block list). And remember, do not make the cure worse that the disease. A mail validation could do that (quite a few sales people found that out)

Comment: Thanks. I have form validation. I am trying to find a way to send verification emails to customers before they submit the form. My goal is to verify that the users own the email address they have entered.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do so. Email is slow and can take up to X years to deliver.(and this has happened on a few rare occasions with specific mail setups). The only thing you could add as a preflight check that works 6/10 times is a dns check for the MX record in the form validation hook. But you are not checking the email address than. Your making an educated guess about an email service.